# How can I Hide excel fill handle in a single file

Tags: excel

Is there a way to hide fill handle option in a single excel file so that it won't affect my other excel file.

Is it possible that this will affect any user who uses that file

Comment: You can turn it off in Excel Advanced Options (Enable fill handles and cell drag-and-drop).  But it will affect Excel rather than the file on its own and only on your computer.  I guess you could use some VBA to turn it on and off when the specific file is opened/activated. [Display or hide the fill handles](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/display-or-hide-the-fill-handle-80918200-9ae9-4615-93c9-13d4f1496f81)

Answer (score 0):

The [Excel Option](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/advanced-options-33244b32-fe79-4579-91a6-48b3be0377c4) to turn off the fill handle is bundled together with enabling drag & drop. Unlike other Advanced Excel Options that may be directed at a single workbook or even a single worksheet, this option is application wide.

[image]

You can turn off the Fill Handle while a single workbook is open. The fill handle will be turned off for any other workbook open at the same time. You can restore the original fill handle state when the workbook is closed.

Once the workbook is saved as macro-enabled (XLSM or XLSB), any user opening the workbook will have the fill handle and drag & drop disabled for as long as the workbook is open¹.

In the ThisWorkbook code sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    toggleDragAndDrop
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    toggleDragAndDrop bOFF:=False
End Sub

Private Sub toggleDragAndDrop(Optional bOFF As Boolean = True)
    Static bDAD As Boolean, bABO As Boolean

    With Application
        If bOFF Then
            bDAD = .CellDragAndDrop
            bABO = .AlertBeforeOverwriting
            .CellDragAndDrop = False
        Else
            .CellDragAndDrop = bDAD
            .AlertBeforeOverwriting = bABO
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

¹ <sub>Providing running macro code is enabled when opening the workbook.</sub>